# Why doesn't `apt-get -f install` happen automatically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

Occasionally with Ubuntu, if my packages get in a tangle, I need to run `apt-get -f install` to fix it.

If this is a routine fix, why doesn't it happen automatically?

Is there any reason I *wouldn't* want to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to indicate that, so far, you have encountered only minor problems in your package handling. An example of such a simple problem occurs when you install *google-chrome*, where the installation fails because of the lack of the *libappindicator1* package, and a simple invocation of *apt-get -f install* will download the missing package, and then resume and complete the installation of *google-chorme*.

Alas, not all situations are so easy. Sometimes you run into truly complex problems, where you need to downgrade some packages so that you can upgrade some other package. Under these conditions, you will likely have several courses open to you, and you will most likely want/need to be able to choose among different possibilities. Even the laying out of the different courses available to you is not standard, and depends upon the tool used. You mention *apt-get -f install* which is a rather simple instrument indeed (but better than its predecessor, *deborphan*, for which I rarely find a use nowadays).

In fact, in these situations I prefer the much more skillful *aptitude*, of which the [Debian Admin Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/) says (page 285):

> **6.4.1.3. Better Solver Algorithms**
>
> To conclude this section, let's note that aptitude has more elaborate algorithms compared to apt-get when it comes to resolving difficult situations. When a set of actions is requested and when these combined actions would lead to an incoherent system, aptitude evaluates several possible scenarios and presents them in order of decreasing relevance. However, these algorithms are not failproof. Fortunately there is always the possibility to manually select the actions to perform. When the currently selected actions lead to contradictions, the upper part of the screen indicates a number of “broken” packages (and you can directly navigate to those packages by pressing b). It is then possible to manually build a solution for the problems found. In particular, you can get access to the different available versions by simply selecting the package with Enter. If the selection of one of these versions solves the problem, you should not hesitate to use the function. When the number of broken packages gets down to zero, you can safely go to the summary screen of pending actions for a last check before you apply them.

So you see that neither the instrument used to solve the *broken* configuration, nor the course of action available to you are as simple as you seem to imply. Thus it is better to leave every user to exercise his free will, by choosing an instrument (*deborphan/apt-get/aptitude/synaptic/the CLI/...*) and a choice of packages whenever this choice is not unambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

Option `-f` (or its equivalent long version, `--fix-broken`) makes `apt-get` attempt to fix broken dependencies. If you ask why it's not enabled by default, I'd say it's a good thing to know when your packages have issues, and *then* correct them.